# Is it possible to track Or recover money from USDT address

Tags: addresses, transfer, usdt, withdrawal, recover

I have been scammed ,long story short i have sent money to an indian account and he has created an account with binance and bought USDT from my money.I have given cyber crime complaint for the same.Police have contacted binance for deposit and transfer details.Suppose if binance gives USDT Transfer address.Would it be possible to trace the person or what are the ways to recover my money.Please help

Comment: The police and Binance should have tools to trace funds.

Comment: Police has asked binance for activity details. I'm from chennai Police said to me that they have not done this before. I'm here asking if anyone has done it or any insights would be helpful